# Function passed as parameter not being called

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that when clicked receives a function passed as an argument and the passed function is also an argument to another function created using JavaScript. The challenge I have is that the passed function is not being invoked.

```js
function alerts(x) {
  document.getElementById('dialogfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="submit(\'' + x + '\')">Yes</button>';
}

function submit(x) {
  x();
}

function callthis() {
  alert('welcome call me');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alerts(callthis)">submit</button>
<div id="dialogfoot" style=""></div>
```

Comment: onclick of button you are not calling the function that you passed as input. call this is not called in alerts method.

Comment: how can i call it as a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the string `'callthis'` in `submit1` rather than the function `callthis`.

```js
function alerts(x){
    document.getElementById('dialogfoot').innerHTML='<button onclick="submit1('+x+')">Yes</button>';
}

function submit1(x){
    x();
}
function callthis(){
    alert('welcome call me');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alerts(callthis)" id='btn'>submit</button>
<div id="dialogfoot" style=""></div>
```

Comment: The submit method is required because in the final code it act as a confirmation code before calling "callthis()". Thanks

Comment: oh yea, let me modify the solution. give me a min.

Comment: fixed it, please see my jsfiddle.

Comment: The issue was with this line: <button on-click="submit1('+ x +')">Yes</button>'. You have added \'' at the start of x and then '\' at the end of it causing issues. Refer to my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/1q3gn65u/15/

Comment: can't find jsfiddle

Comment: I did add it in my answer and prev comment but here it is again : https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/1q3gn65u/15/